# How to save Reactive Form data on refresh / changing page?

Tags: angular

Which would be the best solution to save the data insert by user in a Reactive Form?

In my Angular app i have a stepper, each step is a Reactive Form, when the form is valid the user can go ahead to the next step or get back to previous and change form values.

The issue comes when like the user want change items inside the cart or refresh the page, as there are lot of informations that he is filling out in the forms it would be nice that after refesh or changing the page the data inserted inside the reactive form will be keept in it.

So which would be the best approach to do it? should i go for localstorage, cookies or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LocalStorage` in this case can be a good solution to persist data. in the component `ngOnInit()` check the `LocalStorage` and if there is the related data fill the forms.

You can have a `setLocalStorage()` function which will be invoked on the form change event if keeping every single data persistent is very important to you like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe( val => {
     this.setLocalStorage(val);
  });
}

setLocalStorage( newValue: any ): void {
  // Set Localstorage code here
}
```

Otherwise you can call `setLocalStorage()` on the stepper next button or form submit event or any required event.

Comment: so i should `.set` localstorage for each form in change handler?

Comment: create a set function and call it on the value changes event `this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe()` if it is very important to you to set on localstorage. Otherwise you can call it on the next() button of stepper.

Comment: awesome, didn't know about `form.valueChanges` actually i ended up with this approach for each form:     `this.clienteForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('USER_INFO', JSON.stringify(this.clienteForm.value));
    });`

Comment: While to set the values saved in localstorage as json to Reactive Form, i have to set each Control value or i can like put whole Json object and fill whole form once?

Comment: Cause you are using the ReactiveForm the controls will be set automatically when user enter the data and based on the changes you just have to set the localstorage. But you have to another `getFromlocalstorage()` function that will be called on `ngOnInit()` that if user refresh the page, check the localstrage and set the for value using `set()`